# React Child Component not re-rendering when props change

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a list of nested/grouped checkboxes, where selecting one of the checkbox (parent) should select other checkboxes (all its children) based on a array of data objects. Right now, hard coding the `checked` value in the `App.js` state reflects the checkbox output ticks, but when the state is being modified by  passing the `setState` as props to the child components, the checkboxes do not update.

One hacky way of partially solving what I'm trying to do, is by using a `useState` in the `CheckBoxGroup.js` onChange methods, to change a boolean value, thus forcing the component to update. But even then, the console shows the correct changed props.state, but the app.js component state doesn't reflect. Without the useState, the checkboxes do not seem to re-render as well. Can someone help with this please? 
Thanks

The following is the code. 
Code Sandbox link here: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-haze-ij1km?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import FoodGroup from "./FoodGroup";

export default function App() {
  let arr = [
    {
      name: "Fruits",
      parentId: 100,
      data: [{ value: "Apple", id: 1 }, { value: "Banana", id: 2 }]
    },
    {
      name: "Vegetables",
      parentId: 200,
      data: [{ value: "Potato", id: 3 }, { value: "Onion", id: 4 }]
    }
  ];
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    // basically selecting all id : { selected : true } for parent id and child id
    1: { selected: false },
    2: { selected: false },
    100: { selected: false }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FoodGroup data={arr} state={state} setState={setState} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**FoodGroup.js**

```
import React from "react";
import CheckBoxGroup from "./CheckBoxGroup";

const FoodGroup = props => {
  let groups = props.data.map((group, index) => (
    <CheckBoxGroup
      group={group}
      key={index}
      data={props.data}
      setState={props.setState}
      state={props.state}
    />
  ));
  return <ul>{groups}</ul>;
};

export default FoodGroup;
```

**CheckBoxGroup.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import CheckBox from "./CheckBox";

const CheckBoxGroup = props => {
  // const [a, b] = useState(false);
  const onChildChange = (child, e) => {
    let childSelected = props.state;
    if (!childSelected[child]) {
      childSelected[child] = {};
    }
    childSelected[child].selected = e.target.checked;
    props.setState(childSelected);
    // b(!a); a hacky way I found a work around to force re render the component otherwise it doesn't
    // work
  };

  const onParentChange = (child, e) => {
    let childSelected = props.state;
    if (!childSelected[child]) {
      childSelected[child] = {};
    }
    let childInThatParent = [];
    props.data.forEach(group => {
      if (group.parentId === child) {
        group.data.forEach(item => {
          childInThatParent.push(item.id);
        });
      }
    });
    childSelected[child].selected = e.target.checked;

    childInThatParent.forEach(child => {
      if (!childSelected[child]) {
        childSelected[child] = {};
      }
      childSelected[child].selected = e.target.checked;
    });

    props.setState(childSelected);
    // b(!a);
  };

  let checkboxes = props.group.data.map((item, index) => (
    <CheckBox
      onChange={onChildChange}
      value={item.value}
      id={item.id}
      key={item.id}
      setState={props.setState}
      state={props.state}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CheckBox
        onChange={onParentChange}
        value={props.group.name}
        id={props.group.parentId}
        countrySelected={props.state}
        setState={props.setState}
        state={props.state}
      />
      <ul>{checkboxes}</ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default CheckBoxGroup;
```

**CheckBox.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const CheckBox = ({ state, id, onChange, value }) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value={id}
        onChange={e => {
          onChange(id, e);
        }}
        checked={state[id].selected}
      />
      {value}
    </li>
  );
};

export default CheckBox;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you updating the state in `onChildChange` and `onParentChange` method you are referencing the same state. You can check sandbox for fix:  https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-moon-0e91c

Check `onChildChange` and `onParentChange` method inside CheckBoxGroup.js file

Comment: @RezaGhorbani I was referencing the state directly in `CheckBoxGroup.js` e.g. in line 7. I was using `let childSelected = props.state;` instead of  `let childSelected = { ...props.state };`